# C# HMACMD5 hash producing different result than working JS Code

Tags: c#, cryptography, md5, cryptojs, hmac

I wrote a working JS script used in Postman to test out an API.
It has the hash algorithm and its working fine, but I am unable to get the same hash in my C# code.

I have a computed message and a secret key to use.

In JS I used the built in `CryptoJS.HmacMD5(message,secretkey).toString()` and it works.
Basically i would like some assistance in replicating the above statement to C# code.

```cs
public static string HashHmacMD5(string message, string secret)
{           
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    using (HMACMD5 hmac = new HMACMD5(encoding.GetBytes(message)))
    {
        var msg = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
        var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(msg);
        String test = BitConverter.ToString(hash).ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test)));
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the HMAC generated, then hex encoded and from that the HMAC generated again? Post the CryptoJS code including completet test data.

Comment: If you really only want to port the CryptoJS one-liner, swap `message` and `secret` in the C# implementation. `test` should then return the expected result.

Comment: CryptoJS defines HMAC as `var hash = CryptoJS.HmacMD5("Message", "Secret Passphrase");`. This is entirely idiotic: any implementation uses **key** (not password) then message, so I'm not surprised that you also swapped them in C# code.